# How to send a PDF over Axios and receive over in Actix Web

Tags: pdf, rust, next.js, axios, actix-web

I've been trying to do this multiple ways and it doesn't seem to work. I'm using NextJS so first I call my Next API:

```js
...
      mutateUser(
        await fetchJson("/path/to/api", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/pdf" },
          body: file, // const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
        })
      );
...
```

Then I call my Actix Web server using Axios in the API

```js
...
  const { token } = req.session.user;
  const body = req.body;
  const api_url = `${process.env.SERVER_API_URL}/path/to/api` as string;
  console.log(body.length);

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(api_url, body, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
      },
    });
    res.json({ ...response.data, isLoggedIn: true });
  }
...
```

Then this is how I handle it in Actix:

```rust
pub async fn route_function(db: Data<DatabaseRepository>, mut payload: Payload, auth: AuthorizationService) -> HttpResponse {
    let id = auth.id;
    let mut bytes = BytesMut::new();
    while let Some(item) = payload.next().await {
        bytes.extend_from_slice(&item.unwrap());
    }

    //bytes to string
    log::debug!("bytes: {:?}", bytes);
    // length of bytes
    log::debug!("bytes length: {:?}", bytes.len());

    let pdf_text = match pdf_extract::extract_text_from_mem(&bytes) {
        Ok(text) => text,
        Err(e) => { // PDF parsing error only with Axios
            log::error!("Error: {:#?}", e);
            return HttpResponse::BadRequest().json(ErrorResponse::new("error parsing pdf".to_string(), e.to_string()));
        }
    };
...
```

So basically, what's going wrong is this: When I use Postman or cURL the Rust route works perfectly. Here is my cURL command for reference:

```bash
# This works
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/pdf" -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" --data-binary "@/path/to/file.pdf" http://localhost:8080/path/to/api
```

However, when I use Axios, I get a PDF Parsing error. The PDF parser library returns an error when parsing the PDF Trailer. Additionally, I was checking the bytes length of the requests and when I call using Axios it is around 101k bytes but when I call using Postman or cURL it is 58k bytes. Not sure why but I think this has something to do with why it's not working. This also makes me think that I am doing something wrong with either Axios, Next, or Fetch but I can't find where. I also tried using `FormData()` but that didn't work either.

If someone has a workaround by changing my Actix route so that it works generally, this is also appreciated. I only found how to read a pdf using the `Payload` extractor.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think Axios tries to do various bits of magic with the request, setting `Content-Type` headers and transforming the data; it may be possible to get this working with Axios (I'm not the right person to ask) but it might also be that it's not the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have to do this in next

```js
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

to then use `req` as a readable stream.

Refer to:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/37735
or
https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/tt4qbf/getting_the_raw_request_body_according_to_next_is/

Then you can post this using axios. When you encounter further problems, you might want to consider setting the `Content-Length` Header.

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5223#issuecomment-1690233615